# Set $options reference

Tags: options, codex

I am starting up in theme development and i have searched on codex on the topic of setting theme options.This is is what i am talking about,

```
$options = array (

array( "name" => $themename." Options",
    "type" => "title"),


array( "name" => "General",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),

array( "name" => "Colour Scheme",
    "desc" => "Select the colour scheme for the theme",
    "id" => $shortname."_color_scheme",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
    "std" => "blue"),

array( "name" => "Logo URL",
    "desc" => "Enter the link to your logo image",
    "id" => $shortname."_logo",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),


array( "name" => "Custom CSS",
    "desc" => "Want to add any custom CSS code? Put in here, and the rest is taken care of. This overrides any other stylesheets. eg: a.button{color:green}",
    "id" => $shortname."_custom_css",
    "type" => "textarea",
    "std" => ""),       


array( "name" => "Feedburner URL",
    "desc" => "Feedburner is a Google service that takes care of your RSS feed. Paste your Feedburner URL here to let readers see it in your website",
    "id" => $shortname."_feedburner",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => get_bloginfo('rss2_url')),


array( "type" => "close")

);
```

I took this $options from a tutorial on theme options i am following.Is there an official reference on the topic?.I have looked hard at codex and nothing so far.